# How to create a job in SQL Developer in CST timing?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a procedure named `sales_update` which updates a table named `sales_entry`. I need to create a job in SQL DEVELOPER VERSION 2.1.0. The job needs to be created in **CST timing** daily @ 8 am so as the table sales_entry gets updated by 8 am CST.

How do I do that?

Comment: v2.1 is ancient. go ahead and upgrade to version 4.1. we do have a Scheduler/Jobs node in the tree with a wizard you can use to create jobs that can execute your SP each day at 8AM...

Comment: not sure why you had a down vote but this question isn't easy to find online. therefore, i gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034

Try the link above; basically all you need to do is use the query

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
)
```